# Increment a Character in DAX/PowerPivot

Tags: powerpivot, dax

In excel it is easy to go A + 1 = B by using =CHAR(CODE("A")+1). However, in Powerpivot, both CHAR and CODE functions seem to be gone. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks!
G

Comment: gani, whats your desired outcome? :)

Comment: I am pulling some "encoded" urls from my website right into powerpivot that I need to track. I need to unencode them. I have an codenumber (ie. 1) and I add it to letters and numbers.

For example. If the code is "A45" and the codenumer is "2" then the unencoded code wou5ld be "C67" ( A + 2 = C, 4 + 2 = 6, 5+2 = 7). For this however I need to be able to add "2" to the letter "A". Which seems to be impossible right form inside powerpivot.

As I mention above, this is possible in normal excel using the technique explained above (CHAR(CODE("A")+1)) but not in powerpivot.

Comment: You could probably create a lookup table that has each letter and number and an associated id value so you could just lookup the ID that is 2 greater than the ID for A.

Comment: gani, could you please share an example of such a URL and its desired outcome once processed by PowerPivot? :)